# Как переиспользовать методы во Vue не используя VUEX?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Когда я начал создавать Vue приложение, я через api сервер подтягивал списки пользователей, отделов и т.п. используя vuex store и создавая все действия по взаимодействию с api в store modules, и далее в приложении проводил разные изменения в этих списках.

Мне сказали, что это не совсем правильно, т.к. по сути store - это кэш и правильнее было бы работать сданными напрямую с api, т.к. есть высокая вероятность, что с теми же данными будут работать другие пользователи и я не буду видеть изменений.

Как это правильнее реализовывать? Писать в отдельных компонентах свои отдельные методы для работы с внешним api? И если так, то как лучше разбивать приложение, чтобы методы можно было бы переиспользовать в других компонентах если не использовать store?

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае лучше использовать mixins
И вынести туда всю работу с API

Подробнее можно прочитать тут
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: Спасибо. Я решил реализовать через services